# How can I identify the tables a Microsoft SQL Server view is using?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server and was asked what tables does a certain view gets its data. I tried using the dependencies tab but all I see is the name of the view. What does this mean? I have verified that it is in fact a view.

I tried using

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('NameOfView');
```

I also tried

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'NameofView';
```

Lastly,

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'NameofView';
```

None of these returned anything.

Comment: You can try 
select *
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies
where referencing_id = object_id('NameofView'); and go from there, also check out sys.objects and sys.columns for more details on the objects being referenced

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```sql
SELECT
  referenced_server_name,
  referenced_database_name,
  referenced_schema_name,
  referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.NameOfView', 'OBJECT') r
WHERE r.referenced_minor_name IS NULL;  -- ignore column references
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> what tables does a certain view gets its data

The reality is 99% of people script the view in the SSMS Object Explorer and look at the query executed by the view.  The query contains the tables used.

Right-click the view in SSMS Object Explorer > Script View As > Create To > New Query Window.  The tables used will be displayed in the view script.

I can't think of any good reason to ask this question outside of an interview question to test your knowledge of SSMS or if your co-worker was too lazy to script it out themselves.